# Passing a function with zero v. one argument

Tags: python, parameters

Alright so I have about a kindergarten level question here, and I can get around it - but I decided to bite the embarrassment and just ask it. So in passing arguments, fundamentally, what is the difference?

```
def add(): 
    x = 'Print X'
    print (x)
```

and

```
def add(x): 
    x = 'Print X' 
    print (x)
```

I've been able to make my way coding a bit without really getting this - but what is the difference in how this program is being read?

Don't eat me alive, I know this is basic haha.

Comment: Your second function's argument is completely superfluous since you immediately assign to it it in the function, i.e. `x = 'Print X'` so the ponly difference is that the second requires you to pass something in which  will never have an effect on the function's output...

Comment: However, consider a function `def add(x): print('Print', x)`

Comment: Try calling both functions. You'll notice a difference, and you'll notice that one of them doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check [passing arguments on python](https://www.python-course.eu/passing_arguments.php)

There's no use to "x" on your code, so there's no purpose on passing it as a parameter, when you pass parameters to a function you want that data to be used in the function, for ex:

```
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
```

but if you are gonna overwrite whatever value you are getting as a paraments as soon as you enter the function as you did on:

```
def add(x): 
    x = 'Print X'  <--- here
    print(x)
```

There's no point on it.

however if your code looked at little like this, it could be useful.

```
def add(x): 
    print(x)

add('Print X')
```

Comment: That makes sense @divancontreras - thank you. See it is just little formatting things that I do not know how to explain. Unfortunately i am in the point of coding where I can get around things, but I do not know why they work haha. I am trying to fix that

Answer (score 1):

As far as your particular example is considered, those two functions have no difference in outputs. However, with little modification, you can make one of them, a generalization of other. Consider this:

Function 1:

```
def add(): 
   x = 'Print X'
   print (x)
```

Function 2

```
def add(x): 
   print (x)
```

When the first function is called, it initializes `x` with a string and then prints that string. However, while calling the second function you need to pass a value for x (This is known as an argument and can be "any" value). If you call it like `add('Wow! this is awesome!')` the function will print your string. Since the Function 2 can print any string you give as an argument instead of the hardcoded one I am calling function 2 a generalization of function 1.

Your function 2, takes in a string in the same way like my function 2, but it overwrites the value of `x` with `'Print X'`. Therefore no matter the argument given, it will always print the same string.

Hope this clear things for you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you mix definition and call of a function.

```
def add(x): 
    print (x)
```

is a definition.

```
add ("Print x")
```

calls the function.
Within the scope if the function the variable x has value "Print x"